# Arrays and if statements. How to check if value is in array? *javascript*

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-apps-script

So I have a program that sends emails. The user has a list of emails that cannot be sent to. These are in arrays and I need to use a if statement to determine if what the user entered in is in the array of emails. I tried the in function which didnt work but Im probably just using it wrong. I tried for loops and if statements inside. But that didnt work either. Here is a snapshot of the code Im using to help you get the idea of what im trying to do.

```
function test2(){
  var safe = [1]
  safe[1] = "lol"
  safe[2] = "yay"

  var entry = "lol"
  Logger.log("entry: " + entry)
  for(i = 0; i < safe.length; i++){
    if(entry == safe[i]){
      Logger.log("positive")
    }else{
      Logger.log("negative")
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what I tried with the in function to show you if I did it wrong

```
function test(){
  var safe = [1]
  safe[1] = "lol"
  safe[2] = "yay"

  var entry = "losl"
  Logger.log("entry: " + entry)
  if(entry in safe){
    Logger.log("came positive")
  }else{
    Logger.log("came negative")
  }
  Logger.log(safe)
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with `var safe = [1]`?

Comment: Note from the "future": since 2015, arrays have the `includes()` method, which checks if the array contains the given value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array.indexOf(element) > -1` usually does the trick for these situations!

To expand upon this:

```
if (array.indexOf(emailToSendTo) < 0) {
  // send   
}
```

Alternatively, check this cool thing out:

```
emailsToSend = emailsToSend.filter(function(x) {
  // basically, this returns "yes" if it's not found in that other array.
  return arrayOfBadEmails.indexOf(x) < 0;
})
```

What this does is it filters the list of emailsToSend, making sure that it's not a bad email. There's probably an even more elegant solution, but this is neat.

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked except where you said "//dont send" turned out to be the part to send. But thanks I was really puzzled! These darn arrays :P

Comment: Ha! Accidentally put my > the wrong way, but that works better.

Comment: Note from the "future": since 2015, arrays have the `includes()` method, which checks if the array contains the given value.